# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type C

Tags: c

Well, I'm getting this error and couldn't identify when i'm trying acess the fields.

In my bnum.c, i have the declaration of my struct:

```
    #include "bnum.h"

    struct num {
      char *vet;
      int tam;
    };
```

And in my bnum.h, I have:

```
    typedef struct num *b_num;
```

And in the main file I have:

```
    #include"bnum.h"
    int main(void){
    b_num b;
    b->tam = 5;
```

I'm using gcc on Linux Mint.

Comment: last of your quoted main lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main file does not have access to the structure definition, hence the error. You should move the definition

```
  struct num {
     char *vet;
     int tam;
  };
```

from .c to .h.

Comment: +1.  Worth also pointing out that the code will then fail at runtime, attempting to dereference an uninitialised pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good-organized code.
The struct declaration should be in the header file, this way any src file that will include the header will be
familiar with that struct.